# How these regular expressions count the words in HTML?

Tags: javascript, regex

Can someone please help me with these regular expressions?

```
wordCountTemp = wordCountTemp.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi,"");
wordCountTemp = wordCountTemp.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi," ");
wordCountTemp = wordCountTemp.replace(/\n /,"\n");
```

I don't understand how they work. Below is the full code.

```
function() {
    var wordCountTemp = $("#content").text();
    wordCountTemp = wordCountTemp.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi,"");
    wordCountTemp = wordCountTemp.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi," ");
    wordCountTemp = wordCountTemp.replace(/\n /,"\n");
    var wordCount = wordCountTemp.split(' ').length;
    if (wordCount>3000) return "3k+";
    else if (wordCount>2500) return "2.5k-3k";
    else if (wordCount>2000) return "2k-2.5k";
    else if (wordCount>1500) return "1.5k-2k";
    else if (wordCount>1100) return "1.1k-1.5k";
    else if (wordCount>800) return "800-1.1k";
    else if (wordCount>500) return "500-800";
    else if (wordCount>200) return "200-500";
    else return "<200";
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the question, what is your goal, what issues have you run into and what results have you gotten?

Comment: @Toni2708 You might find this helpful http://eloquentjavascript.net/09_regexp.html

Comment: Hi @Hodrobond I'm just trying to find out what is matched by /(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi, /[ ]{2,}/gi or /\n /,"\n" in a text example. Thanks for the guide @mrbubbles! Maybe you guys can tell me how i get this div.mk-main-wrapper-holder:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) to a query selector format in the var wordCountTemp = $("#content").text(); line. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help guys! I got it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi,"")
```

> If it starts `^` with any `*` white space `\s` OR `|` if any `*` white space `\s` up to the end `$` replace it with nothing `""`.

```
.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi," ")
```

> At least two or more `{2,}` consecutive spaces `[  ]`  , replace with one space `" "`.

```
.replace(/\n /,"\n")
```

> A newline `\n` and a space , replace with just a newline `\n`. That's like a trim at the EOL.

So in short these regex are cleaning any sloppy white spaces which ensures an accurate word count.